# NPE annotation scenarios and static-analysis tools for Java

Tags: java, static-analysis, nullpointerexception

Here is a number of code snippets that can throw NullPointerException.

01:

```
public void m1(@Nullable String text) {
    System.out.print(text.toLowerCase()); // <-- expect to be reported.
}
```

02:

```
private boolean _closed = false;

public void m1(@Nullable String text) {
    if(_closed)
       return;

    System.out.print(text.toLowerCase()); // <-- expect to be reported.
}
```

03:

```
public void m1(@NotNull String text) {
    System.out.print(text.toLowerCase());
}

public @Nullable String getText() {
    return "Some text";
}

public void m2() {
    m1(getText());  // <-- expect to be reported.
}
```

Different people have access to different static-analysis tools. It would be nice to collect information, what tools are able to detect and report the issues, and what are failing. Also, if you have your own scenarious, please, publish them.

Here my results

**FindBugs (1.3.9):**

- 01: [S] Parameter must be nonnull but is marked as nullable
- 02: [F] not reported
- 03: [F] not reported

**IntelliJ IDE 9.0.2 (Community edition):**

- 01: [S] Method invocation text.toLowerCase() may produce java.lang.NullPointerException
- 02: [S] Method invocation text.toLowerCase() may produce java.lang.NullPointerException
- 03: [S] Argument getText() might be null

**[Checker Framework (1.0.7):](https://checkerframework.org/)**

- 01: [S] dereference of possibly-null reference text
- 02: [S] dereference of possibly-null reference text
- 03: [S] incompatible types. found: @Nullable String, required: @NonNull String

**Annotations packages:**

```
javax.annotation.* // JSR 305
edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.* // FindBugs
org.jetbrains.annotations.* // IntelliJ
checkers.nullness.quals.* // Checker Framework
```

Comment: Since you asking for multiple people to contribute answers, you might want to mark this community wiki.

Comment: please specify, from which package  @Nullable and @NotNull come from, because they are not part of Java 6.

Comment: 1. Marked as community wiki. 2. Different tools seems to have their own annotation libraries. For IntelliJ they came from org.jetbrains.annotations.*, and for FindBugs it was edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.* But the library was called annotations.jar in both cases.

Comment: Great question. It would also be interesting to see what other features related to NPE the tools offer, e.g. lazy-nonnull from the Checker Framework.

Comment: IntelliJ also lets you configure the inspection (Constant Conditions and Exceptions) to use whatever annotations you want for your `@Nullable` and `@NonNull` annotations. So for example, you can use the FindBugs annotations if you want. That way you can see the same errors in your IDE that FindBugs will catch.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that FindBugs treats @Nullable and @CheckForNull quite differently -- the former is basically saying "I have no idea whether this is supposed to allow null or not" and the latter says "This method explictly allows nulls".  My team had much more useful FindBugs results when we globally changed all @Nullable to @CheckForNull in our code, since the latter is what we really had meant.

Comment: Yes, good point... Thought the provided tests results are the same when I used CheckForNull or Nullable for FindBug.

Comment: @alex2k8: interesting.  I wonder if a more recent version of FindBugs has changed that?

Comment: The current version of FindBugs is 1.3.9 (the one I used in my tests).