# Is there any tool for detecting possible NullPointerException in class member variable

Tags: java, android

We have a NullPointerException after we created an object with below class for sure, because member variable mTest is null,

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    private String mTest;

    // the setter is not being called after the object is created
    public void setTest(String test) {
        mTest = test;
    }

    // ok, the activity is starting and will crash 
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mTest.replace("a", "b");
    }

}
```

in some activity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
// we forgot to set the member variable...
startActivity(intent);
```

We are using SonarQube and Android Studio for detecting null pointer deferencing but neither of them can detect the above problem. Is there any suggestion? I know the programmers should not code these bugs but I am more interested in detecting them instead of fixing them.

Thanks!

Comment: debug using break points

Comment: yes, it is fixing the bug but not detecting the bug.

Comment: Use a try/catch to check for NullpointerException?

Comment: @Atrakeur - read the Question.  That is not what he is asking.

Comment: yes, it does find 'Read of unwritten field mTest in ...', but if I add a setter which isn't being actually called, Findbugs won't be able to detect.

Comment: It probably can't detect it because the actual construction and `onPostCreate` call is done by the Android framework. Anyway, how exactly are you going to call `setTest` from an `Intent` when you don't even have access to the constructed activity object? I believe the correct pattern would be to put some custom extras in the intent for `SettingsActivity` to read and handle.

Answer (score -1):

I would try Findbugs and PMD.  If neither of those detect the bug, the next thing to try would be to see if you could create a custom PMD checker that would detect this.

Actually, statically detecting cases where a reference field is used before before it is initialized is likely to be difficult.  I have a feeling that your example is one of the few cases that might be tractable.  Consider this variation for example:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    private String mTest;

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mTest.replace("a", "b");
    }

    public void setTest(String test) { mTest = testl; }
}
```

Determining whether the suspect line could result in an NPE requires an analysis of the code base to see is `setTest` is ever called.  And even then, you've only determined that an NPE *may* not occur ... not that it *will* not occur.

---

References:

- [Is there any tools for finding Null pointer exception in java files..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724627/is-there-any-tools-for-finding-null-pointer-exception-in-java-files)
- [NPE annotation scenarios and static-analysis tools for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794928/npe-annotation-scenarios-and-static-analysis-tools-for-java) - which talks about a different, but related problem.
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26224/Static-Analysis-on-Steroids-Parasoft-BugDetective - BugDetective uses flow analysis which is more likely to find problems with uninitialized variables.

Comment: Yes, it seems this NPE is difficult for Findbugs and PMD to analyse at this moment.

Comment: @neo.orz.hk - The issue is actually broader than NPEs. The problem is that finding bugs of this nature involves 1) global analysis, 2) analysis of control flows to determine (in this case) whether one event can happen before another one.  By contrast, Findbugs and PMD are limited to looking for suspicious patterns in the code structure.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a try/catch block and let the catch block look like this:

```
catch (Exception e){
e.printStackTrace(System.out); 
}
```

Here the System.out can be replaced by any output format(logger,                      printwriter, etc)

Comment: I think you have completely misunderstood the Question.  The OP wants a tool for statically detecting the bug ... not instructions on how to catch the resulting exception.

Comment: netbeans IDE has warned me of 'possible null access' (domt remember exact name) and i believe eclipse IDE would also offer.

Comment: it does if the class doesn't contain a setter. But my case is the class has the setter but it is never been called.